# IIS Workerprocess crashed

Tags: opencover

I'm working on a Asp.net web application code base and I have installed OpenCover 4.7.1221 version and using command prompt Administrator mode I executed a command to generate a code coverage report in a Windows Server 2012 R2 server and after few minutes it gives worker process crashed error and it also covers part of the code until that error occurs.I have executed same command  against same code base in my windows 10 machine and it works fine and OpenCover generated a complete report.

**Executed command :**
OpenCover.Console.exe -target:C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -targetDir:"C:\Projects\Application\src\Application.Web\Bin" -targetargs:-debug -register:Path64 -output:"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Opencover report\results.xml" -communicationtimeout:10000000

[image: Error Message]

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the full saved error details. The `APPCRASH` event name suggests it's just an unhandled exception - (if WebForms) don't you have a `Global.asax` global error handler or an `AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException` handler?

Comment: yes this is a WebForms application Global.asax is there but since this is working fine in Windows 10 machine is it possible to have unhandled exceptions

Comment: But you shouldn't be having _any_ unhandled exceptions though.

Comment: Yes I added log to the Application_Error  method in Gloabl.asax then executed the command again , No error logged

Comment: Add a handler to `AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException` - and also consider implementing a handler for `AppDomain.Current.FirstChanceException` which simply performs _unbuffered_ disk/log-file exception logging - that'll help pin things down too.

Comment: Also, check your Windows Event Logs (especially the Application log) as that will contain two or three separate logged events for every fatal .NET Framework app-crash (look for EventId `1026` from _.NET Runtime_ and EventId `1000` from _Application Error_, and EventId `1001` from _Windows Error Reporting_. The most useful one is the `1026` event as that should contain a .NET exception stack-trace.

Comment: Event log -Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x545055fe
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005561
Faulting process id: 0x2524
Faulting application start time: 0x01d81801bb9098a5
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
Report Id: 7b208385-83f5-11ec-8105-005056a4d0bf
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: